# Kion signifas "duonkruda"?

Tags: meaning

> Ne manĝu ĝin duonkrudan,... (Biblio, Eliro 12:9)

Mi komprenas la kombinaĵon (duon+kruda), sed mi ne komprenas la signifo de duon vorton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supozeble tio signifas ke la manĝaĵo estas duone kruda. T.e., ke ĝi ne estas plene kuirita, sed meze inter kuirita kaj kruda. Aŭ ke oni kuiris ĝin nur la duonon de la bezonata tempo.

---

Presumably that means that the food is half raw. Ie, it’s not fully cooked but halfway between cooked and raw. Or for example that it has been cooked for only half of the time needed.

Answer (score 3):

Parafrazita oni povas diri

> Ne manĝu ĝin duonkrudan

kiel

> Manĝu ĝin bone kuirita